# Who moved my parent site from Space.SE to another site?

Tags: support, moderator, chat, user-accounts

I thought I was the only one able to do this? Someone moved me from Here to Physics.SE where I was suspended preventing me from chatting here and everywhere for a year. This is not right?? Can you as a moderator make it possible for me to chat here at least. It happened when I was chatting on Physics.SE.

Comment: A Physics mod did, presumably, as they [didn't want you chatting on Physics while you were suspended on Physics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49178775#49178775).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313637/why-was-this-user-banned-from-chat/313638#313638

Comment: For what it's worth, there are a number of proposals to make site and chat suspensions sync up better in various ways; the current codebase makes it impossible to suspend someone from chatting in a single site's chatrooms.

Comment: See also this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267725/271002

Comment: Just to clarify: Muze, you have had a rather high number of warnings on various sites, and have been shown and told various rules and guidelines. Dissembling to imply innocence is not very convincing.

Comment: Muze - you have been told. When you get suspended for low quality, you get a message telling you. Same as for every other mod message you get. Also, once you have been told off a lot on one site, don't expect to play innocent on another site. We expect you to take comments on board for every site. Oh, and getting heated is not going to help you.

Comment: @RoryAlsop If I knew then what I know now I would not be suspended, I just want a clean slate after suspension not to have to tip toe.

Comment: Btw, Muze, I would like to start some discussion on the related meta sites in your defense, but I am not sure, what you want and what did you really do. The PSE would likely suspend also me, if I would try to defend you too vehemently, but the other sites would likely not. It is particularly problematic that they used the mod of an unrelated site to suspend you. I think it could become a well-defensible case on the Meta SE. The problem is two: 1) lack of information to me 2) the risks would be too high for me 3) it is unlikely that your privileges would be given back, but it would be possible

Comment: to show a clear position to the System and for the decision-makers what they would likely listen in the future.

Comment: @peterh Re:  "It is particularly problematic that they used the mod of an unrelated site to suspend you.". Let me make this clear: the Physics mods had absolutely zero involvement in Muze's chat suspension (induced by reparenting). It was my decision alone. That said, you're definitely welcome to raise a Meta SE post regarding this.

Comment: @Blue If I understand it well, the activity on your site was that the PSE mods contacted you, that Muze talks on the chat, and they can't suspend him, because his chat account is not linked with his PSE account. It means that Muze had a clean history on your site. Giving 1 year for him with a clean history seem serious over-reaction to me.

Comment: @Blue I don't want to create a MSE case, because Muze currently doesn't communicate also with me. I have no way to know his view about his last (3rd!!!) yearlong PSE ban, which is the real cause of the current events. Furthermore, mentioning induvidual suspensions is forbidden on the PSE meta, and I have no way to know, how widely would the PSE mods interpret their this rule.

Comment: @peterh Muze doesn't have *any* [activity](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/5886/muze?tab=activity) on Quantum Computing and naturally (by extension) has a "clean history" there. Their chat suspension wasn't related to their Quantum Computing history *at all*. At this point, I should remind you that *all* SE moderators are chat moderators. I just happened to be present in The h Bar when Muze entered and I noted that they were trying to evade their Physics suspension by using the Physics chat to ask questions. That prompted me to carry out the reparenting.

Comment: [cont.] Nevertheless, I don't see why're getting so worked up about the chat suspension. As I mentioned in my answer, I have already lifted it.

Comment: @Blue You say talking on the PSE chat with an ongoing PSE suspension is evading the rules. I say, reparenting a user who has nothing to do to your site, which results a 1yr long chat ban for him, is also circumventing the rules.

Comment: @peterh "I say, reparenting a user who has nothing to do to your site, which results a 1yr long chat ban for him, is also circumventing the rules." I don't agree. But you're certainly allowed to raise it on meta as I said. Or even better: use the "[contact us"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form. That way you can directly speak to the SE community managers.

Comment: @Blue Thanks the lift! It is rare that an once given punishment is lifted. Thanks!

Comment: @Blue I think after it is unlikely that he will talk on the PSE chat again -> there won't be reason for yet another suspension.

Comment: @peterh I'm all for giving second chances, but keep in mind that it's quite stressful for us to deal with difficult users day in and day out. If Muze doesn't follow the instructions this time, they'll probably have their ban reinstated.

Comment: @Blue I think in his case, consecutively given 1 month bans would have enough pedagogical value. Note also, he has many highly upvoted, popular posts. The SE sites could work also as popularization of the science, which is imho a major motivator of the volunteer work here. He is good in that, at least if we see his not deleted posts. But I see a strong movement to expel him. I think it is bad. If he has bad posts, it could be downvoted, closed and so on. His good posts attract many visitors, which is essential for a site network.

Comment: @Blue yes thank you again. I don't have a problem for being suspended. I just have a problem for be suspended years at a time for very minor stuff that everyone else is allowed to do. Can the suspensions be coded to be more dynamic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90266/discussion-between-muze-and-peterh).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Who moved my parent site from Space.SE to another site?

I did ([mod on Quantum Computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/26/blue)).

> I thought I was the only one able to do this?

No, all [chat moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) can re-parent users.

> Someone moved me from Here to Physics.SE where I was suspended preventing me from chatting here and everywhere for a year. This is not right?

If your chat parent was Physics SE you would have been automatically suspended from all chat rooms on the Chat Stack Exchange server. It shouldn't be a matter of *luck* that one user gets suspended from chat just because their chat parent happened to be the same as the main site they got suspended on while another user gets to use *all* the chat rooms freely just because they happened to have a different chat parent. C.f. Shog9's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267725).

You [were told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49178775#49178775) that you shouldn't be chatting on Physics SE chat while you were suspended on the Physics SE main site. Since you didn't seem to get the point and continued to chat there, I reparented your chat account manually. You're currently suspended on three sites on the network (namely [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/103579/muze), [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/4139/muze) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/148704/muze)) and have a history of not listening to instructions. You should realize that dealing with repeated behavior of this kind is aggravating for the moderation team. The clear point here is: don't try to use chat to circumvent main site suspensions. Avoid those chat rooms which are hosted on sites where your main account is suspended, during the period of the suspension.

Nevertheless, I am willing to give you another chance and have lifted your one-year suspension. Please keep the above instruction in mind. Try to improve your participation on the main sites (the ones you're not currently suspended on) in the meanwhile (i.e. in the next one year). Ask good questions, write good answers and show respectable behavior. Most importantly, follow the rules! You will then be welcome to visit and use all chat rooms. I can understand that it often feels like we're bogging down users with unnecessary rules and restrictions, but trust me that's exactly what helps us keep SE largely free from spam and trollish behavior.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90448/discussion-on-answer-by-blue-who-moved-my-parent-site-from-space-se-to-another-s).